# XCode 4.5.2: When editing xib file, Menu->Editor->Add Horizontal|Vertical Guide is greyed out. Why?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, interface-builder, xib

This occasionally happens when I'm editing xib files. On certain occasions simply clicking the associated view controller file and then clicking back on the xib file has resulted in the menu options being re-enabled. Not today however.
This behaviour/defect has been funky since the days of XCode 3, and yet I still can't google anybody who's posted a question about this or received an answer.
Thanks!

Comment: Here we are in 2015, and in XCode 6.4 I am still having problems with this functionality! Sad. If we wrapped Steve Jobs in copper wire and put a magnet in the grave his spinning corpse would power a small city!

Comment: I was also getting this but after reading the docs I actually clicked on a view on the canvas rather than selecting it in the sidebar and it worked.

Comment: @amergin, I will investigate that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking on a control (not a view), and see if the menu items are enabled.

Comment: Nick, clicking on a control doesn't help. When they work, these guidelines are really handy for UI design, but they've been kind of broken for me all the way back to XCode 3! Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

As @amergin said, you have to select the view on the canvas, and not in the sidebar.